# Text input's changed value not returning

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

when i run my web app then many textbox is coming with their initial value. when i change the textbox value and click on button then change value is not reflecting rather old value is returning. first time i face this issue. i clear browser cache but still no luck.

this way i am extracting value from textbox.

```
alert(tr.find("input[id*='FirstName']").attr('value'));
OR
alert(tr.find("input[id*='FirstName']").val());
```

just do not understand why this is happening. last day event run my program successfully but today facing this issue. i search google but no luck. looking for help to fix it. i try to replicate the issue [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/fmdu7xbq/2/)  but here i am not getting any problem.

### My html in td look like as follows

```
<td class="NameColWidth">
    <span class="display-mode">Sandip</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenFirstName" value="Sandip" name="HiddenFirstName">
    <input type="text" value="Sandip" name="Students[0].FirstName" id="Students_0__FirstName" data-val-required="First Name Required" data-val="true" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">
    <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Students[0].FirstName" class="field-validation-valid text-danger"></span>
</td>
```

the hidden field causing problem ?

Comment: you can get the value of input `$("#HiddenFirstName").val()`

Comment: i just remove hidden field and program start working. anyone can say why hidden field causing problem?

Comment: Calling .val() on a jQuery object (which represents a set of nodes, not just a single node) will return a single value. jQuery picks the first node in your set to interrogate, so you were getting the value of the hidden input, as you expected. Either target your element more specifically, or filter out the hidden input.

Comment: `tr.find("input[id*='FirstName']"` will find exactly hidden field and will return its value

Comment: how to specify text here along with input tr.find("input[id*='FirstName']").val() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden filed was causing the problem. when you try to get all input fields that id contains FirstName also gets hidden field because it exists in the same row and id contains FirstName.

to ignore that hidden filed you can do

> tr.find("input[id*='FirstName']").not("input[type='hidden']")

OR

> tr.find("input[id*='FirstName']:not([type=hidden])")

also note, if your query result returns collection/array to other function then jquery by defaults picks up only 1st item from that collection and changes that only

EDIT 
to answer the question asked in comment, you can find text value by

> tr.find("input[type='text'][id*='FirstName']").val()

remember, this will get only 1st text value not all.

Comment: how to specify text here along with input tr.find("input[id*='FirstName']").val() ?

Comment: can i write something like tr.find("input type='text' [id*='FirstName']").val() ?

Comment: give new code which will only select input and type text?

Comment: tr.find(input[type='text'][id*='FirstName']").val() you can do it this way. but remember this will get only 1st element value

Comment: i will try and let u know.

Comment: what will be the code for dropdown `tableRow.find("input[type='select'][id*='cboState']").val()` does it work?

Comment: should work bro tr.find("select[id*='cboState']").val()